# Getting ENAMETOOLONG

Tags: nativescript

Getting the following message when trying to build for android

`Processing node_modules failed. Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG`

nativescript 2.4 and android 2.4.1 - all updated.

npm version 3.10.8

node 6.9.1

also using SCSS

I googled and looks like it has to do with windows command line limit.

Comment: Need help here...my development has come to a halt because of this.

Comment: I finally was able to get it to work by uninstalling a plug-in - nativescript-dev-sass and re-installing it. Most probably all I did was defer the error.